# PHP: инициализация свойства класса, вызовом метода

Tags: php

```
class Foo()
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return 'FooBar'
    }
    public x = $this->bar();
}
$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->x;
```

При попытке выполнить этот код получаю ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   D:\index.php on line 7

Я понимаю, что ошибка в попытке присвоения свойству данных, возвращаемых функцией. Объясните, пожалуйста, теорию - что происходит не так?

Comment: Какую цель вы хотите достичь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете инициализировать свойство статическим методом, который общий для всех экземпляров данного класса

```
public $x = self::foo();
```

Обычным методом не можете. $this - это ссылка на текущий объект. На момент объявления класса объекта еще просто не существует, он начинает существовать только после выделения под него памяти, при объявлении ключевым словом new.

Comment: Спасибо! Доходчиво объяснили.

Answer (score 3):

У вас попытка присвоить непонятно чему (у икса нету $) нечто из контекста экземпляра класса (`$this` указывает на текущий экземпляр). А в данной области видимости экземполяра быть не может.